# Error go.mod: no such file or directory Compiler docker compose local package

Tags: docker, go, build, docker-compose, microservices

I have a problem when I build with docker compose an application with local dependencies to create a docker image.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:alpine AS build 

ENV GOPATH=$GOPATH
#GOPROXY
ENV GOPROXY=http://proxy.golang.org
ENV GO111MODULE=on


WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/github.com/julianskyline/motorcars-core-business

COPY . . 


# Set OS as linux
RUN GOOS=linux go build -o $GOPATH/bin/github.com/julianskyline/motorcars-core-business main.go

FROM alpine
COPY --from=build $GOPATH/bin/github.com/julianskyline/motorcars-core-business $GOPATH/bin/github.com/julianskyline/motorcars-core-business
ENTRYPOINT [ "/go/bin/motorcars-core-business" ]
```

```
My go.mod

module github.com/julianskyline/motorcars-core-business

go 1.15

replace (
    github.com/julianskyline/errors => /home/julianmarin/proyectos/go/src/github.com/julianskyline/errors
    github.com/julianskyline/motorcars-db => /home/julianmarin/proyectos/go/src/github.com/julianskyline/motorcars-db
    github.com/julianskyline/motorcars-models => /home/julianmarin/proyectos/go/src/github.com/julianskyline/motorcars-models)
```

Projects are in the same folder:

$GOPATH/src/github.com/julianskyline/errors
$GOPATH/src/github.com/julianskyline/motorcars-core-business

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnDxN.png)

The go build/run work fine.

Error sudo docker-compose build:

```
 Step 6/9 : RUN GOOS=linux go build -o $GOPATH/bin/github.com/julianskyline/motorcars-core-business main.go
 ---> Running in 45227441dfdd
go: github.com/julianskyline/errors@v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000 (replaced by /home/julianmarin/proyectos/go/src/github.com/julianskyline/errors): reading /home/julianmarin/proyectos/go/src/github.com/julianskyline/errors/go.mod: open /home/julianmarin/proyectos/go/src/github.com/julianskyline/errors/go.mod: no such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c GOOS=linux go build -o $GOPATH/bin/github.com/julianskyline/motorcars-core-business main.go' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Service 'api' failed to build
```

NOTE: The file /home/julianmarin/proyectos/go/src/github.com/julianskyline/errors/go.mod exists!

Comment: ...inside the image?  What does your Dockerfile set `ENV GOPATH=...` to?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't copy correcly my Dockerfile, The ENV GOPATH is $GOPATH (in my pc /home/julianmarin/proyectos/go/)

Comment: "/home/julianmarin/proyectos/go/src/github.com/julianskyline/errors/go.mod exists"; it exists on your PCs filesystem but not in the docker containers filesystem.

Comment: if the docker file is located in `$GOPATH/src/github.com/julianskyline/motorcars-core-business` then `COPY . .` does not include `/home/julianmarin/proyectos/go/src/github.com/julianskyline/errors`

Comment: @mh-cbon I'm sorry, I was travel... Perfect, That was the problem thanks!

Comment: Please post the answer. I have the same problem but not sure how to fix it

Answer (score 4):

The `Dockerfile` is in `$GOPATH/src/github.com/julianskyline/motorcars-core-business` which means that the `COPY . .` within it [will only copy](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) `$GOPATH/src/github.com/julianskyline/motorcars-core-business` into the docker image.

The `go.mod` contains [`replace`](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace) directives that reference folders not under `$GOPATH/src/github.com/julianskyline/motorcars-core-business` (e.g. `$GOPATH/src/github.com/julianskyline/errors`); this leads to compilation errors because those folders are not present within the docker image.

To resolve this you can:

- Copy the entire `julianskyline` folder into the image (by moving `Docker` file into the parent folder, specifying the context on [the command line](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#specify-a-dockerfile--f) or using [`docker-compose`](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.golang/blob/master/autopaho/examples/docker/docker-compose.yml#L28)).
- Remove the `replace` directives and letting `go` pull the files from github.

*Posting answer as this was requested in the comments; I believe the comments provided sufficient info for the OP.*

Comment: Thank you. It did provide enough info, I just didn't like moving the dockerfile up and couldn't find other solutions so having your solution clarified really helped :)